Using ipfw and pf together
I would like to use pf and ipfw at the same time for different tasks, but I can not understand who is activated first (if there is an order) when a rule is received.
Also trying to verify this, I can’t figure out where the pf and ipfw log files are located on both OPNsense and FreeBSD. Please, help me.
Thanks in advance!

The processing order depends on theirs modules load order, unsure which one is first but it's trivial to test out even without logs, say, comparing counters per rules.
